# Excel - criar um top 10 com todos os records

Tags: microsoft-excel

Eu tenho um site onde gera estatisticas em .txt, esse txt depois e gerado em excel com todos os resultados.
O meu objetivo e criar um top dos artigos mais visualizados.
Isto e exemplo:

No bloco de notas tem:

```
                 ID        |      Nome artigo clicado

                   1                           Rato
```

Sabendo que vai exisitir mais doque 100 ids iguais, eu quero que o excel verifique e faca contagem do mesmo id...

Comment: Os arquivos em txt estão em csv? Separados de que maneira? Espaços e quebra de linha?

Comment: Estao seprados desta forma exemplo 230:carro sao separados por “:”

Comment: Mas a minha questao nao e essaa, pk eu ja criei o excel, apenas quero que no excel eu proprio crie uma funcao que verifique os repetidos , conteos e faca um genero de top10 dos mais contados

Comment: Já experimentou usar uma tabela dinamica com contagem e filtrando por valor em "10 Mais" ?

Comment: Isso que eu ia falar, faça que nem na dica do @Isac. Crie uma tabela dinâmica e ordene os valores do maior para o menor ou do Top 10. Ou uma função VBA para importar o .txt automaticamente e classificar os dados numa matriz. Você pode encontrar várias funções para trabalhar com vetores e matrizes no [CPearson](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx).